# Is there a way to exclude infos from the problems count in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, omnisharp

The problems tab in my Visual Studio Code installation has recently started showing a huge amount of "infos".
I have no idea why it started doing this now. find it really distracting as until now, I'd used the problem count as an indicator for warnings and errors.[The problem count is almost at 800, yet most of the problems are infos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvcwm.png)

I've searched for a setting all over VScode, but haven't found one.  I tried changing OmniSharp Logging level, and that did nothing.

Comment: these are linting problems, change/disable rules of your CS linter

Comment: What is a linter?

Comment: you have installed and configured that tool, what does a web search tell you

Comment: Is that something that comes with .NET sdk or the VSCode C# addon?  I have neither installed or configured a linter as far as I know

Comment: I've also done several web searches, but all of the solutions I found to my problem have been for Visual Studio, making them inapplicable for VScode.

Comment: do you mean that `linter` is only mentioned for VS for searches

Answer (score 0):

turns out the problem was caused by changes done by an extension I had installed.  Making a clean reinstallation of VsCode helped.